# Joining two strings with a comma and space between them

Tags: javascript, string, string-concatenation

I have been given the two strings `"str1"` and `"str2"` and I need to join them into a single string. The result should be something like this: `"String1, String 2"`. The `"str1"` and `"str2"` variables however do not have the `", "`.

So now for the question: How do I join these strings while having them separated by a comma and space?

This is what I came up with when I saw the "task", this does not seperate them with `", "` though, the result for this is “String2String1”.

```
function test(str1, str2) {

    var res = str2.concat(str1);

    return res;

}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this:

```
 function test(str1, str2) {

     var res = str2 + ',' + str1;

     return res;

 }
```

Comment: You are probably looking for @thefourtheye's solution: .join(", ")

Answer (score 51):

Simply

```
return str1 + ", " + str2;
```

If the strings are in an Array, you can use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method, like this

```
var strings = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(strings.join(", "));
```

**Output**

```
a, b, c
```

Answer (score 11):

That's it:

```
strings = ["str1", "str2"]; 
strings.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the strings.

```
res = str1 + ', ' + str2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `concat()` with multiple params.

```
a = 'car'
a.concat(', ', 'house', ', ', 'three')
// "car, house, three"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function test(str1, str2) {

var res = str1+", "+str2;

return res;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My trick is to use `concat()` twice (with chaining).

```
var str1 = "Hello";
var str2 = "world!";
var result = str1.concat(", ").concat(str2);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result;
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3Ljc/2/)

Comment: You could actually chain them, like this `str1.concat(", ").concat(str2);`

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do this:

```
function test(str1, str2) {
    return Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ", ");
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that handling arbitrary number of arguments makes the function significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

Google led us here, and apparently nobody mentions what we were after:

```
function metJoinStrings(varpString1, varpString2, varpSeparator) {
  return varpString1 + (varpString1 === '' ? '' : varpSeparator) + varpString2;
}
```

With this approach, the end result is presentable as expected, and consequently splittable afterwards.
IMPORTANT: one could want to verify or manage the presence of 'varpSeparator' in the source strings, and act accordingly.

Also, parameter type validation should be added.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of way to do this:

```
var str1 = "Hello";
const str2 = "world!";

const result1 = str1+", "+str2;

const result2 = `${str1}, ${str2}`;

const result3 = str1.concat(", ").concat(str2);

const strings = [str1, str2];
const result4 = strings.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

We should also consider the false case, if values are not present.

```js
function joinString(str1, str2, delimiter) {
    const first = str1 || ''
    const second = str1 && str2 ? delimiter : ''
    const third = str2 || ''

    return `${first}${second}${third}`
}

console.log(joinString('A', 'B', ' ')) // Output A B
console.log(joinString('A', 'B', ',')) // Output A,B
console.log(joinString('', 'B', ' ')) // Output B
console.log(joinString('A', '', ' ')) // Output A
console.log(joinString('', '', ',')) // Output
console.log(joinString(null, '', ',')) // Output
```

We can write the function code in one line also but for more readability divided into small part

Other solution but it will give error if your input is empty. so always check for string is valid or not.

```js
function joinString(str1, str2, delimiter) {
 
    return str1.concat(str1 && str2 ? delimiter : '').concat(str2)
}

console.log(joinString('A', 'B', ' ')) // Output A B
console.log(joinString('A', 'B', ',')) // Output A,B
console.log(joinString('', 'B', ' ')) // Output B
console.log(joinString('A', '', ' ')) // Output A
console.log(joinString('', '', ',')) // Output 
console.log(joinString(null, '', ',')) // Output Error
```

Answer (score 0):

For whoever's dealing with variables that may or may not be empty, and needs to add spacing only when necessary, this solution works for me:

```js
let string1 = "tipo"
let string2 = ""
let string3 = "HGT"

[string1, string2, string3].filter(Boolean).join(" ")
```

Result:

```
tipo HGT
```

(notice the lack of the extra spaces)